# casace delete in api flask using Sqlalchaemy

Tags: sql, api, flask, sqlalchemy

```
@app.route('/question/<question_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
@token_generator
def delete_question(current_user, question_id):
    """This function is use to delete question by user"""
    question = Questions.query.filter_by(id=question_id,
                                         user_id=current_user.id).first()

    if not question:
        return jsonify({'message': 'No question found!', "status": "404"})

    DB.session.delete(question)
    DB.session.commit()

    return jsonify({'message': 'Question item deleted!, "status": "200"'})
```

I want to delete all answers     `@app.route('/question/<question_id>/answers', methods=['DELETE'])`

when deleting question `@app.route('/question/<question_id>` which i am deleting.

My answers api

```
@app.route('/question/<question_id>/answers', methods=['GET'])
@token_generator
def get_all_answers(current_user, question_id):
    """This function is use to get all answers by user"""
    answers = AnswersDatas.query.filter_by(question_id=question_id,
                                           user_id=current_user.id).all()

    output = []

    for answer in answers:
        data = {'id': answer.id, 'solution': answer.solution, 'solved': answer.complete}
        output.append(data)

    return jsonify({'answers': output})
```

Comment: You are using SQLAlchemy for managing your models, right?

Comment: @MihailFeraru yes sir

Answer (score 0):

Want you need is named cascade deleting. You basically need to create a relationship between your `Questions` model and `AnswerDatas` model, a one-to-many relationship I think.

It goes something like this:

```
class Questions(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Questions'

    answers = relationship("AnswerDatas", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

You can find more about how this work in SQLAlchemy [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html).